# All colour has gone from my libre office Calc charts

Tags: libreoffice

I am running Libre Office v7.3.6.2 in Xubuntu 22.04.1 and have several Libre Office Charts which I have maintained for a number of years. Recently the charts have lost all colour, so the bars have become invisible. You can see that there is something there because there are breaks where they cross axis lines. I have tried formatting the series, but it has no effect. Although I have a reasonable understanding of computers I am just at the "user" level. I have tried searching for an answer but can't find anything, please can someone help.

Answer (score 1):

Well I've fixed it. First I tried opening the spreadsheets on other computers, they were fine. Then I tried uninstalling Libreoffice and reinstalling it - no effect, still had the same problem. Finally I reloaded Xubuntu from scratch and reinstalled all my apps. Now the spreadsheets look fine. I can only assume something went wrong when I upgraded Xubuntu.

UPDATE: I've finally found the actual cause of my problem. In the Appearance dialogue of XFCE I had selected the "High Contrast" style. It would seem that Libre Office interprets this as monochrome. Switching to another style (I'm using Adwaita) and everything goes back to normal. I'm not convinced that High Contrast and Monochrome are synonymous but hey ho!